# Crashed: com.apple.CFNetwork.LoaderQ SIGABRT ABORT

Tags: ios

I'm getting this crash in my iOS app, and I'm not sure what's causing it:

```
Crashed: com.apple.CFNetwork.LoaderQ
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1bf365df8 __abort_with_payload + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1bf35f838 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1bf35f7d4 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 34
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1be9a14b4 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 112
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1be9a140c __objc_error + 42
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1be9bc018 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::AutoreleasePoolPage((anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage*) + 142
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1be9bb094 objc_autoreleasePoolPush + 68
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1bf1e4e9c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 + 272
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1bf1e5b2c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 468
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1bf1e6d70 _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 1892
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1bf1edf14 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bf3ec0dc _pthread_wqthread + 312
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1bf3eecec start_wqthread + 4
```

This crash is being reported by Crashlytics. It doesn't look like anything interesting is happening in any of the other threads and none of it includes any lines from my app code. Do you know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Seems like memory cleanup is going on. Could it be that some object is released too many times?

Comment: Hmm...not sure, do you think it might be something in my app code or still part of CFNetwork?

Comment: That's not an either-or question... It can be something in your code that causes a crash in CFNetwork. Specifically, it seems that something gets autoreleased even though it's already not in memory.